# Eigenvalue of the product of two positive definite matrices while one of them is non-symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm interested in the eigenvalues of the product of two positive definite matrices $AB$ while A is symmetric (all eigenvalues are real with condition number $m$) and B is not necessarily symmetric (could have complex eigenvalues). By positive definite, I mean $x^\top A x > 0$ holds for any real vector $x$. Particularly, let's say the eigenvalue of B has the form $\lambda_i = a_i + b_i j$ and define $\kappa_B = max_i \frac{b_i}{a_i}$. Then what's the largest possible $\kappa_{AB}$ for $AB$? $m * \kappa_B$?